# Combined two table with different column in mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine two tables with different column names but I can’t get the right result:

**Table 1:**

```
   date                      userID
2015-09-08 23:31:04             3
2015-09-08 23:31:05             3
```

**Table 2:**

```
   leave                     userID
2015-09-08 23:31:10             3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
   userID                leave                    date
      3           2015-09-08 23:31:10   
      3                                    2015-09-08 23:31:04 
      3                                    2015-09-08 23:31:05
```

I used this following query below but the output is not what I need.

```
  SELECT UserID FROM table1 
   UNION ALL 
  SELECT UserID FROM table2
```

My question is it possible to combine the 2 tables with the output I want? If it's possible could you help me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT UserID, null, `date`
  FROM table1 

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT UserID, `leave`, null
  FROM table2
```

Comment: Okay I will try it. Thanks for the answer. If that is work I'll accept the answer